# How to extract extension of input file parameter using Windows batch script

Tags: windows, batch

Given this batch script - how do I isolate filename and extension, like in the output given:

```
@echo off
REM usage split.bat <filename>
set input_file="%1"
echo input file name is <filename> and extension is <extension>

c:\split.bat testfile.txt
input filename is testfile and extension is txt
```

That is - what's the correct syntax for `<filename> and <extension>` in this code?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### How do I isolate filename and extension from `%1`?

Use the following batch file (split.bat):

```
@echo off 
setlocal
REM usage split.bat <filename>
set _filename=%~n1
set _extension=%~x1
echo input file name is ^<%_filename%^> and extension is ^<%_extension%^>
endlocal
```

Notes:

- `%~n1` - Expand `%1` to a file Name without file extension.
- `%~x1` - Expand `%1` to a file eXtension only.
- `<` and `>` are special characters ([redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)) and must be [escaped](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) using `^`.

Example usage:

```
> split testfile.txt
input file name is <testfile> and extension is <.txt>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [parameters](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) - A command line argument (or parameter) is any value passed into a batch script.
- [redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) - Redirection operators.
- [syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html) - Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes.

Comment: Right - %~n1 and %~x1 is the missing sauce, thank you.