# Rewrite the first three characters of *.ext file names in a folder with a set of letters

Tags: windows-10, command-line, file-extension, batch-rename, prefix

How to rewrite the first 3 letters of file name

- Using set alphabet: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789 to randomise characters
- Targeting all files of a particular extension in a folder *.ext
- Duplication of 3 characters by chance does not matter (46,656 variables already)
- Batch script solution to run in a windows environment.
- Prefer script to be simple to reduce run time.

Suggested code and breakdown. Note: I still have no idea how to code.

- Original:

  ```
  032_name.ext
  039_name.ext
  0D8_name.ext
  333_other.txt
  ```
- Write Over the top of first three characters

  ```
  XXX-name.ext
  ```
- After

  ```
  D7K_name.ext
  L2V_name.ext
  720_name.ext
  333_other.txt
  ```

Make batch file (SetRename.bat or SetRename.cmd) then run command like:

```
SetRename %r *.ext   /or/ SetRename %r3%name% *.ext  /or/ SetRename
```

- Code 1 adapted from DavidPostill, example of full solution

  ```
  @echo off
  setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
  rem initialise counter
  set "alphabet=A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"
  rem process jpg and png files
  for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %%i in (`dir /b *.ext *.ex2`) do (
    rem split into name and extension
    set _name=[reduce 3 characters]]%%~ni
    set _ext=%%~xi
    rem do the rename
    ren "%%i" "!y!-!_name!-!_ext!"
    increment counter
    set /alphabet "%Random%"
    )
  endlocal
  ```
- Code 2 adaptated from 3 SU posts

  ```
  @echo off

  setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

  set "alphabet=A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"

  for %%a in (%alphabet%) do (
      set "a.!name!=%%a"
  set o=-%3 [reduce by 3] 

  )   
  set "y="
  for /l %%a in (1 1 3) do (
      set /a "r=!random!"
      for %%b do set "y=!-%3!!r!!name!"
  )
  echo(%y%

  endlocal
  ```

Current Research:

- [SU File rename with suffix as 01 02 03 04 etc (and Further Reading)](https://superuser.com/a/1060597/900431)
- [SU How do I isolate filename and extension from %1?](https://superuser.com/a/1131907/900431)
- [SU Rename files by command line](https://superuser.com/a/353642/900431)
- [SU Rename Files Random Batch File](https://superuser.com/a/776801/900431)
- [SU - How do I remove the same part of a file name](https://superuser.com/a/236840/900431)
- [SU Command Prompt Rename Prefix](https://superuser.com/a/871799/900431)
- [Stack Overflow on Random Strings:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30630254/7811302) [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30630254/7811302) [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46596181/7811302) [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37208671/how-do-i-get-a-random-letter-output-in-batch)
- [ss64 - Random Syntax](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-random.html)
- [ss64 - REN Rename Command](http://ss64.com/nt/ren.html)
- [wikibooks - Windows Programming/Programming CMD](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Programming/Programming_CMD)
- [Informit  - Windows Batch Files](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1154761&seqNum=13)
- [techguy - Random Numbers and Letters](https://forums.techguy.org/threads/random-numbers-and-letters.803268/)

Comment: You made a right mess of my code :)

Comment: I certainly did, what a mess! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I rewrite the first 3 letters of a set of file names with random characters?

Use the following batch file (SetRename.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "_chars=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
for %%f in (%*) do (
  rem split into name and extension
  set "_name=%%~nf"
  rem remove first 3 characters from _name
  set "_name=!_name:~3!"
  set "_ext=%%~xf"
  rem create a 3 character random prefix
  set "_prefix="
  for /l %%n in (1 1 3) do (
    set /a i=!random!%%36
    for %%i in (!i!) do (
      set "_prefix=!_prefix!!_chars:~%%i,1!" (
      )
    )
  echo ren "%%f" "!_prefix!!_name!!_ext!"
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- remove `echo` when you are happy with the `ren` command

Example usage:

```
> dir /b
032_name.ext
039_name.ext
0D8_name.ext
333_other.txt
SetRename.cmd

> SetRename *.ext

> dir /b
333_other.txt
C42_name.ext
FZW_name.ext
MYQ_name.ext
SetRename.cmd

> SetRename *.ext

> dir /b
333_other.txt
A6O_name.ext
A8H_name.ext
H5P_name.ext
SetRename.cmd
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [EnableDelayedExpansion - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [For - Loop through files - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html)
- [Parameters / Arguments - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- [variable edit replace - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html)
- [variable substring - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)